# Reduce spacing in PyQt5 - GridLayout - Between the widgets

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, pygui

I am new to PyQt5, I created a grid layout as shown in figure I want to reduce the gap between the three widgets, I tried playing around margins, spacing and row stretch but none have worked, Please look ar the image in hyperlink and help me :

Image:
[image]

```
def createlayout(self):
    self.label1=QLabel(self.label,self)
    self.label2=QLabel(self.label2,self)
    self.label3 = QLabel("try", self)
    self.textbox = QLineEdit(self)

    vbox=QGridLayout()


    vbox.addWidget(self.label1,0,0,1,1)

    vbox.addWidget(self.textbox,1,0,1,1)

    vbox.addWidget(self.label2,2,0,1,1)

    vbox.addWidget(self.label3, 3, 0, 1, 1)

    vbox.setContentsMargins(1,0,0,0)
    #vbox.setAlignment('AlignCenter')
    vbox.setRowStretch(0, 0)
    vbox.setRowStretch(1, 0)
    vbox.setRowStretch(2,0)
    vbox.setColumnStretch(1,0)
    #vbox.setRowStretch(2,1)
    vbox.setRowStretch(3,0)
    vbox.setSpacing(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> QGridLayout::setRowStretch(int row, int stretch)
>
> Sets the stretch factor of row row to stretch. The first row is number 0.
>
> The stretch factor is relative to the other rows in this grid. Rows with a higher stretch factor take more of the available space.
>
> The default stretch factor is 0. If the stretch factor is 0 and no other row in this table can grow at all, the row may still grow.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.createlayout()

    def createlayout(self):
        self.label1 = QLabel("self.label")
        self.label2 = QLabel("self.label2")
        self.label3 = QLabel("try", )
        self.textbox = QLineEdit()

        vbox = QGridLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.label1, 0, 0)
        vbox.addWidget(self.textbox, 1, 0)
        vbox.addWidget(self.label2, 2, 0)
        vbox.addWidget(self.label3, 3, 0)
        
        vbox.setRowStretch(4, 1)                                 # +++

        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.resize(300, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but if i want to increase the space between textbox and "Self.label2" should I use stretch again or something else?

Comment: @Omi  sorry, but you did not write this in the question. Formulate a question and show what you want to receive?

Comment: I formulated new question